# Error: format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument -wformat

Tags: c

I get two error messages:

```
Error: format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument -wformat

Error: format '%f' expects an arguemnt of double but argument 4 has type int -wformat
```

I looked it up and tried to fix it, with no avail. Below is my code.
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
  #include <stdio.h>       
  int main() {
    int n = 5, a[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};  // Declare & initialize array of length 5
    int sum;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + a[i];

    printf("Enter an integer x: %d");       // Prompt the user
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);        // Read in the integer

    // Print out the sum, the division we're performing, and the result (without truncation)
    // E.g., The sum of the array is 25; 25/2 = 12.500000

    printf("The sum of the array is $d; %d/%d = %f\n", sum, sum, sum / x);

    // Declare an integer variable y and initialize it using a hexadecimal constant.
    // Print y in decimal, hex, and with leading zeros so that we get the output
    // y = 4011 = fab = 0xfab =   fab = 0000fab

    int y = 0xfab;
    printf("y = %d = %x\n", y, y, y, y, y);
    return 0;
```

Comment: You can't have `printf("Enter an integer x: %d");` without giving it an integer to print as a parameter. The `%d` requires an int parameter to follow. Also `printf("The sum of the array is $d; %d/%d = %f\n", sum, sum, sum / x);` has four `%` specifiers, but only 3 parameters being passed to satisfy them.

Comment: "format '%f' expects a matching 'int' argument" - are you sure that's the exact message?

Comment: "format %d expects a matching int argument" and "format %f expects an argument of double but argument 4 has type int"

Answer (score 2):

You are using printf in a wrong way:

```
 printf("Enter an integer x: %d");
```

You have to specify the integer value to print at %d occurrence, like this:

```
 printf("Enter an integer x: %d",someValue);
```

Also this is wrong:

```
 printf("The sum of the array is $d; %d/%d = %f\n", sum, sum, sum / x);
```

You are printing an integer using %f. You should do the following, instead:

```
 printf("The sum of the array is $d; %d/%d = %f\n", sum, sum, ((double)sum / (double)x));
```

Comment: I tried that and  this is the output i get:


Enter an integer x: 02   (the 0 isnt supposed to be there)
The sum of the array is $d; 32770/32770 = 16385.000000
y = 4011 = fab

Comment: @user3236142 You are saying sum/sum but you are calculating sum/x

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
printf("The sum of the array is $d; %d/%d = %f\n", sum, sum, sum / x);
```

I believe you wanted this instead:

```
printf("The sum of the array is $d; %d/%d = %d\n", sum, sum, sum/x);
```

Note that the last `%f` becomes `%d`, because `sum/x` will yield an integer.

This is also wrong:

```
printf("Enter an integer x: %d");
```

Drop the `%d`, you can't pass format specifiers and then miss the corresponding argument.

Comment: I see only three format specifiers... (Hint: one of the `d`s is prefixed with a `$`, not a `%`)

Comment: @user3236142 no, that's not working. In the example in the comment you said "E.g., The sum of the array is 25; 25/2 = 12.500000". Using %d you cannot print such value, it would simply print "12". If you want to print as in the example you should follow the fix in my answer.

Comment: okay thank you! i am not getting any compilation errors now, but i am also not getting the desired output:

i get the following:

Enter an integer at x: 04   //the zero isn't supposed to be there..i enter the 4 and 

I get: 

The sum of the array is $d; 32770/32770 = 8192.500000
y = 4011 = fab

help?!

Comment: @HAL9000: looking into that right now! thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct yet:

`printf("Enter an integer x: %d");`

You also have to include the arguments at the end inside the end-bracket but outside double quotes by using a comma and the argument. As it is where data is stored(variables)!

This is the correct way:

`printf("Enter an integer x: %d", argument/variable);`